# Can a TensorFlow queue be reopened after it is closed?

Tags: queue, tensorflow

I would like to enqueue items, close the queue to ensure that other sessions will dequeue all remaining items, then reopen it later for the next epoch. Is this possible?

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(...)
close_q = q.close()
reopen_q = #???

with tf.Session([...]) as sess:
    [...]
    sess.run(close_q)
    [...]
    sess.run(reopen_q)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to re-open a closed queue, but (only if you are using multiple sessions) there is a workaround::

1. Create your queue in a [`with tf.container(name):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#container) block that wraps only the queues, and where `name` is not used for any other `tf.container()` blocks.
2. Before you want to reopen the queue, call [`tf.Session.reset(..., [name])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.reset), where `name` is the name of the container you created in step 1. This will cause the queue to be recreated on its next use, and it will be in the opened state.

Comment: Thanks again and again! :)

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What do you insert instead of the dots? When I call `tf.Session.reset(target=None, [name])`, the session will be closed. Do I have to create a new session then? Cheers!

Comment: @mrry what is the standard approach to achieve the same thing, ie train for multiple epochs, without using a workaround?

Comment: The new (v1.2) tf.contrib.data: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data