# TensorFlow: How can I evaluate a validation data queue multiple times during training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

### tl;dr

How can I evaluate a validation set after every K training iterations, using separate queues for training and validation data, without resorting to separate `tf.Sessions` in multiple processes? There doesn't seem to be a clean way to achieve this, given my particular problem, and my current workaround (which I thought would work) gives me undefined behavior. Help!

### The whole story

I want to evaluate a validation set every K training iterations, and I cannot figure out how to implement this properly in TensorFlow. This should be one of the most common operations, yet it feels that TensorFlow's API/architecture is working against me here or is at least making things unnecessarily difficult.

My assumptions are:

- [A1] The multi-process model for training/validation as described here https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/#multiple_input_pipelines is not applicable to my problem, as I have to assume there is not enough GPU memory available to load the variables twice.
- [A2] I want to evaluate on the validation set every K training iterations.
- [A3] Both training and validation data cannot be simply read from disk, but are generated on-the-fly. This makes it impossible to reliably pre-compute the size of the validation set in advance.
- [A4] The validation set is too large to pre-compute and store onto disk.
- [A5] The effective validation set size is not necessarily a multiple of the batch size.

The training input pipeline is set up as follows:

- A `tf.train.slice_input_producer()` generates a (shuffled) list of filenames, each referring to raw input data.
- A custom data generation function generates a variable number of training exemplars/labels from each chunk of raw input data.
- The generated training exemplars/labels are queued via `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` before being fed into the network.

Due to [A3], [A4], [A5], the validation input pipeline is set up in an almost identical way, except that the final input queue is generated via `tf.train.batch()`, since shuffling is not desirable. Due to the above assumptions, a feed_dict based approach is also infeasible, and also seemingly incompatible with using a higher level function such as `tf.train.batch`.

However, a straightforward implementation using two different sets of queues for training and validation does not work. As far as I understand, I have two options:

- [B1] Set the `num_epochs` argument of the validation `tf.train.slice_input_producer` to `None`.

  In this case, the validation set is cycled through endlessly, but I would need to know the size of the validation set in advance to explicitly limit the number of batches to evaluate per run through the validation set. Furthermore, if the validation set size is not divisible by the batch size, I will always pull a bit more in the last batch. As this would shift the order of evaluation of the validation data each time, this is not acceptable.
- [B2] Set the `num_epochs` argument of the validation `tf.train.slice_input_producer` to `1`, and additionally set the `allow_smaller_final_batch` argument of the `tf.train.batch` function to `True`.

  In this case, the validation set is cycled through exactly once, after which the respective queue is closed forever. By default, this will make evaluating the validation set two or more times impossible. Since I do not know of a good way to reopen a queue in TensorFlow, I need to work around this limitation.

Due to the greater limitations of option [B1], I chose to work around the issues of option [B2] instead. The (pseudo-)code outlining my current approach is as follows:

The training loop should be fairly canonical. Every K iterations, a function to evaluate the validation set is called.
Note that I only start the queues that have a name starting with "train_"; these is the queue set up for collecting generated training data. In order to do this, I created two helper functions, `get_queues_by_name` and `start_queue_runners`.

```
def train_loop(train_ops, vali_ops, ...):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        sess.run([tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables()])
        load_latest_snapshot(sess, loader, snapshot_file)

        # Launch the queue runners
        queues = get_queues_by_name("train")
        threads = start_queue_runners(sess, coord, queues)

        try:
            for step in range(start_iteration, num_train_iterations):
                # Runs the session on validation set
                if step % K == 0:
                    validation_results = run_validation(vali_ops, snapshot_file)

                # TRAINING:
                # ...

        except Exception as e:
            coord.request_stop(e)
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

The helper functions look like this:

```
def get_queues_by_name(name):
    """Retrieves all queues that contain the string given by 'name'"""
    all_queues = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS)
    return [q for q in all_queues if name in q.name]


def start_queue_runners(session, coordinator, queues):
    """Similar to tf.train.start_queue_runners but now accepts a list of queues instead of a graph collection"""
    with session.graph.as_default():
        threads = []
        for queue in queues:
            log("Queue", "Starting queue '%s'" % queue.name, level=2)
            threads.extend(queue.create_threads(session, coordinator, daemon=True, start=True))
    return threads
```

In the `run_validation` function, my chosen workaround against the issue of a closed queue is to create a new `tf.Session`. I also only start the threads associated with the queue collecting validation set data.

```
def run_validation(ops, snapshot_file):  # Called inside train_loop()
    results = None
    loader = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        sess.run([tf.initialize_local_variables()])
        load_latest_snapshot(sess, loader, snapshot_file)

        # Launch the queue runners
        queues = get_queues_by_name("eval")
        threads = start_queue_runners(sess, coord, queues)

        # Performs the inference in batches
        try:
            # Evaluate validation set:
            results = eval_in_batches(ops, sess)
        except Exception as e:
            coord.request_stop(e)
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)

    return results
```

I do not know whether creating a new `tf.Session` here is a good idea, but it seems like the only way to accomplish restarting the validation queue. Ideally, I also wouldn't want to re-load the model snapshot, as this seems conceptually unnecessary.

The issue with this code is that I see erratic/undefined behavior during running, such as NaN's or Inf's appearing inside the network during validation set evaluation. This seems to occur predominantly when the validation set queue is being filled at the same time as the training set queue is still being filled (since the training queue is open during validation set evaluation). For example, this very often happens if I evaluate the validation set at iteration 0 (when both queues still need to be filled). It almost seems as if the training/validation queues share some global state, although they are running in a different session.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how I can solve this more cleanly while taking my above assumptions [A1]-[A5] into account?

Comment: You can reopen an existing queue using reset, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39209186/419116 . There shouldn't be any global state sharing between queues which would cause NaN, could it be that NaN are a normal side-effect of your neural network numerics that are unrelated to your queue setup?

Comment: I already double checked that the NaNs are not a normal side-effect of the neural network. If I comment out the `start_queue_runners` call inside `train_loop()`, disable the training ops completely, and evaluate a freshly loaded model snapshot, then no NaNs appear. If I however uncomment the `start_queue_runners` line again, NaNs start appearing on the same model snapshot. The occurrence of these NaNs is non-deterministic (i.e. in different batches, and their number might vary).

Comment: I will be looking into the tf.Session.reset() function and report back on this. Can you give me a pointer what the `target` argument (i.e. the execution engine) should be?

Comment: For local sessions, target is "". About NaN's, the NaN is typically caused by trying to evaluate 0/0 or infinity-infinity. You can run `tf.add_check_numerics_ops` to track down where this computation is happening, and then add `tf.Print` statements around to see why you are seeing a 0 or infinity there

Comment: I have tried to use `tf.Session.reset()` by adding a respective `tf.container()` block around the eval queues and passing the session as a parameter to `run_validation()`. Inside the latter, I removed the with-block, the var. init., and the snapshot loading, and added the `reset` call. This however seems to also close the session, which is *not* what I'd want. I just want to reset the evaluation queues and leave everything else unchanged, such that I can evaluate the validation set repeatedly.
I'm not quite sure what the point of resetting the queues is if the whole session is gone, too (?).

Comment: The NaNs appear non-deterministically in what should be a deterministic operation (loading the model, and performing inference on a number of batches).
For some reason, inserting `debug_op = tf.add_check_numeric_ops()` and then running the group op together with the other ops locks up execution of the program; not sure why.
I *could* add `check_numerics` in some select places, and can ensure that the NaNs are not coming from the data input.
Everything becomes deterministic without NaNs if I do not start the training queue threads, with everything else equal!

Comment: Clarification of the last sentence: Running the validation [in the first iteration] becomes completely deterministic without dreaded NaNs if I do not start the training queue threads, with everything else equal. I.e. just commenting out `start_queue_runners()` in `train_loop()`. I just cannot do any training then, for lack of incoming data. But running the training data queues parallel to the validation will produce NaNs. I would assume the training queues to be completely independent from the evaluation of the validation [queues?], but they are somehow not, given my code.

Comment: I have also tried adding `server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()` and passing it to the session, but then, the `tf.Session.reset()` call effectively behaves like a no-op, i.e. it doesn't matter whether I call it or not, the validation set queues seem to not get reset. If I do *not* add the `tf.train.Server.create_local_server()` call, then the `tf.Session.reset()` call immediately results in closing the session, as mentioned above.

Comment: Hm, maybe it only works for Session("grpc://...")? Either way, it awkward right now, there's feature [request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4535#issuecomment-266531485) to make it easier

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently facing a similar problem. So far I avoided any queues at all and just feeding in the data via the `feed_dict` but I'm obviously loosing some performance by not using queues and parallelism (although I'm still happy with the current speed as I did the same in Theano earlier). Now I want to redesign this and use queues and stumbled upon this problem. There are [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514), [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4535), [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951) related issues.

I'm currently thinking about doing it this way:

- In training, I want to use a `RandomShuffleQueue` which makes it even more complicated. I think I will just ignore the problem and once the reader thread which enqueues tensors into the queue finishes, I will let the training stop, so I loose the remaining up-to `capacity` items for this epoch and just use it for the next epoch. Maybe to make it deterministic I check in the train-thread that I still read from the queue until there are only `min_after_dequeue` items left.
- In evaluation, I want to use the same graph and the same session. I can use `tf.cond` to read from another separate queue instead of the `RandomShuffleQueue`. Or I could use `feed_dict` in evaluation. If I would use a separate queue, I would use a `FIFOQueue` and carefully track that I do the right amount of steps. I could also introduce another dummy tensor which I enqueue into the queue which gives me a `end_of_epoch` flag or so, so then I know in the eval-thread when to stop.

---

In TensorFlow 1.2, there will be the `tf.contrib.data` interface ([issue comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4535#issuecomment-302713431), [documentation overview](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/data/README.md#randomly-shuffling-input-data), [API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data)), which provides the `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` API which also supports shuffling similar as `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` and batching and looping over multiple epochs. Also, you access the data by creating an iterator over it and you can reset the iterator. Some related StackOverflow questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132307/tf-contrib-data-dataset-repeat-with-shuffle-notice-epoch-end-mixed-epochs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132579/feed-data-into-a-tf-contrib-data-dataset-like-a-queue).