# tf.contrib.data.Dataset repeat with shuffle, notice epoch end, mixed epochs?

Tags: tensorflow

About the `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` (from TensorFlow 1.2, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/data/README.md)) usage:
When I use `repeat` (for multiple epochs) together with `shuffle` (as `read_batch_features` does internally), how will I notice when some epochs ends, and what the current epoch is? Also, when the epoch ends, will the `ShuffleDataset` wait first to dequeue everything or will it already be filled with more data from the next epoch? In the last epoch, or if I don't use `repeat`, will the `ShuffleDataset` dequeue all remaining data, like `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` dequeueing does after close?

My current solution, which also gives me more control: I would not use `repeat` but go once over the data and use `ShuffleDataset` to get shuffling like `RandomShuffleQueue`, and then at some point I get `OutOfRangeError` and I know that I reached the end of the epoch. Then I reinitializable the iterator, like it is described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/data/README.md).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior of [`Dataset.shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) depends on where in your pipeline it appears relative to the [`Dataset.repeat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat):

- If you `shuffle` **before** the `repeat`, the sequence of outputs will first produce all records from epoch `i`, before any record from epoch `i + 1`.
- If you `shuffle` **after** the `repeat`, the sequence of outputs may produce records from epoch `i` before or after epoch `i + 1` (and, epoch `i + k`, with probability that increases with the `buffer_size` and decreases with `k`).

If you want to perform some computation between epochs, and avoid mixing data from different epochs, it is probably easiest to avoid `repeat()` and catch the `OutOfRangeError` at the end of each epoch.

There are some more interesting pipelines you could build to track the epoch number. For example, you could encode an epoch number as a component of each element:

```
dataset = (
    Dataset.range(None).flat_map(lambda epoch_num: 
        Dataset.zip(
            (Dataset.from_tensors(epoch_num).repeat(),  # Infinite repeat of `epoch_num`.
             ...,  # Definition of a Dataset over a single epoch.
            )
        )
    )
)
```

...where `...` is the expression that defines a `Dataset` for a single epoch, and includes batching and shuffling.

Comment: Thanks, so that's mostly what I do. Maybe follow-up question: If I shuffle before the repeat, will the repeat repeat the same queue order, so it is not reshuffled for each epoch?

Comment: If you pass an explicit (and non-zero) `seed` to the `Dataset.shuffle()`, it will repeat in the same order; if you don't pass a seed, it will reshuffle in each epoch.