# TensorFlow TFRecordDataset shuffle buffer_size behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

It's unclear to me what the `buffer_size` parameter in [tf.TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/TFRecordDataset#shuffle) does. Let's say we have the following code:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
```

Does this mean that only the first 10k samples will be used and repeated forever, or will I go through the entire dataset? If not, what does it to exactly? And what about this code?

```
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(buffer_size=10000).batch(batch_size)
```

I've noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132307/tf-contrib-data-dataset-repeat-with-shuffle-notice-epoch-end-mixed-epochs), but it doesn't say anything about `buffer_size`.

Comment: There is a standard example in the official document. I think the `buffer_size` is similar to the memory capacity for data prefetching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096625/5098368) might be useful to better understand the `buffer_size` parameter of the `shuffle` method.

In short, the dataset will always have more than `buffer_size` elements in its buffer, and will shuffle this buffer each time an element is added.

So having a buffer size of 1 is like not shuffling, having a buffer of the length of your dataset is like a traditional shuffling.

---

To understand the right order between shuffling and repeating the dataset, please look at the official [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/performance/datasets_performance#repeat_and_shuffle).

The best practice is usually to shuffle then repeat, as this will ensure that you see the whole dataset each epoch.

Comment: Thanks, the other answer explains it quite well and it's really useful to keep it in mind!