# How to enable Dataset pipeline has distributed reading and consuming

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, distributed-computing

It is easy to use two threads that one keeps feeding data to the [queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues) and the other consumes data from the queue and perform the computation. Since the TensorFlow recommends [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) as input pipeline after 1.2.0., I would like to use the `Dataset` and its `iterator` to accomplish the task above, namely:

1. There are two **processes**, one feeds and the other consumes;
2. The pipeline suspends either it is full or empty and it stops when computation finishes at consuming.

P.S. Why in the tutorial of [Threading and Queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues), TensorFlow uses `thread` instead of `process`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132579/feed-data-into-a-tf-contrib-data-dataset-like-a-queue) is related or might be the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed [`tf.contrib.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data) pipelines are not yet supported as of TensorFlow 1.3. We are working on support for splitting datasets across devices and/or processes, but that support is not yet ready.

In the meantime, the easiest way to achieve your goal is to use a `tf.FIFOQueue`. You can define a `Dataset` that reads from a queue as follows:

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(...)

# Define a dummy dataset that contains the same value repeated indefinitely.
dummy = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensors(0).repeat(None)

dataset_from_queue = dummy.map(lambda _: q.dequeue())
```

You can then compose other `Dataset` tranformations with `dataset_from_queue`.

Comment: when will the support for distributed dataset be added?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I would also be appreciated if you are willing to update or post new answer once you have finished your work on distributed `tf.contrib.data`.@mrry