# resetting a Tensorflow graph after OutOfRangeError when using Dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use [the `from_generator` interface for the Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#from_generator) to inject multiple "rounds" of input into a graph.

On my [first attempt](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/93c955b26a329cf2e34c932abff86199), I used the [`repeat()` function](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/93c955b26a329cf2e34c932abff86199#file-repeated_offset_feed-py-L35) to cause the generator to be run 3 consecutive times. However, the [`batch_join` call](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/93c955b26a329cf2e34c932abff86199#file-repeated_offset_feed-py-L41) with a batch size that is *not* an even multiple of the number of iterations per round (10 iterations with a batch size of 3), data from different "rounds" / "epochs" end up in the same batch (depending on the order the tensors are processed; there is some parallelism in the graph).

On my [second attempt](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/9bbe3b91cccb1d1c565302e1e9789ef6), I tried to re-run the iterator after each epoch was done. However, as soon as [`tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` is thrown](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/9bbe3b91cccb1d1c565302e1e9789ef6#file-dataset_feed_reset-py-L64), all subsequent calls to [`sess.run()` on the output of the batch call](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/9bbe3b91cccb1d1c565302e1e9789ef6#file-dataset_feed_reset-py-L59) throw `OutOfRangeError` again, even after [rerunning the iterator's initializer](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/9bbe3b91cccb1d1c565302e1e9789ef6#file-dataset_feed_reset-py-L67).

I would like to inject multiple rounds of input in succession into a graph and not have them overlap like the first example (e.g. using `allow_smaller_final_batch` on the batching options). Some of the kernels I instantiate in my custom Tensorflow fork are very expensive to restart, e.g. `mmap`ing a file of O(10gb), so I'd like to somehow get the best of both of these worlds.

Comment: Please add a small runnable sample that shows your input pipeline, so that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: This should be runnable with the master branch of the Tensorflow repository, needed for the from_iterator function for Dataset. If this example doesn't work with that version, I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem stems from using `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` (which supports reinitialization) with `tf.train.batch_join()` (which uses TensorFlow queues and queue-runners, and hence does not support reinitialization).

I'm not completely clear what your code is doing, but I think you can implement the entire pipeline as a `Dataset`. Replace the following fragment of code:

```
my_iterator = MyIterator(iterations=iterations)
dataset = ds.Dataset.from_generator(my_iterator, 
output_types=my_iterator.output_types, 
output_shapes=my_iterator.output_shapes)
#dataset = dataset.repeat(count=repetitions)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_elem = iterator.get_next()

#change constant to 1 or 2 or something to see that the batching is more predictable
ripple_adds = [(tf.stack((next_elem[0], next_elem[1] + constant)),) 
for constant in ripple_add_coefficients]
batch = tf.train.batch_join(ripple_adds, batch_size=batch_size, 
enqueue_many=False, name="sink_queue")
```

...with something like the following:

```
my_iterator = MyIterator(iterations=iterations)
dataset = tf.contrib.data.from_generator(my_iterator,
                                         output_types=my_iterator.output_types,
                                         output_shapes=my_iterator.output_shapes)

def ripple_add_map_func(x, y):
  return (tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(num_ripples)
          .map(lambda r: tf.stack([x, y + r])))

dataset = dataset.flat_map(ripple_add_map_func).batch(batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
batch = iterator.get_next()
```