# Tensorflow Dataset.from_generator fails with pyfunc exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, yield, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying tensorflow's nightly 1.4 as I need [`Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#from_generator) to stich together some variable length datasets. This simple code (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45928467/281545)):

```
import tensorflow as tf

Dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset
it2 = Dataset.range(5).make_one_shot_iterator()

def _dataset_generator():
    while True:
        try:
            try:
                get_next = it2.get_next()
                yield get_next
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                continue
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            return

# Dataset.from_generator need tensorflow > 1.3 !
das_dataset = Dataset.from_generator(_dataset_generator,
                                     output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
das_dataset_it = das_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        print(sess.run(it2.get_next()))
        print(sess.run(das_dataset_it.get_next()))
```

fails with the rather cryptic:

```
C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_55.py
0
2017-10-01 12:51:39.773135: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is int32, but expects int64
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 467, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    c_api.TF_GetCode(status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is int32, but expects int64
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0"]()]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OneShotIterator_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_55.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(sess.run(das_dataset_it.get_next()))
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Dropbox\_\PyCharmVirtual\TF-NIGHTLY\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is int32, but expects int64
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_INT64], token="pyfunc_0"]()]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OneShotIterator_1)]]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note the generator works fine as:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for k in _dataset_generator():
        print(sess.run(k))
```

prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_5 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

As expected.

Is it a bug, a missing feature or me grossly misunderstanding something ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#from_generator) method is designed to connect non-TensorFlow Python code to a `tf.data` input pipeline. For example, you can yield simple Python objects (such as `int` and `str` objects), lists, or NumPy arrays from a generator, and they will be converted into TensorFlow values.

However, in your example code, you are yielding the result of `it.get_next()` which is a `tf.Tensor` object. This is not supported.
 If you need to capture an iterator in a different dataset, you can use `Dataset.map()` over a dummy dataset, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

Dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset
it2 = Dataset.range(5).make_one_shot_iterator()

das_dataset = Dataset.from_tensors(0).repeat().map(lambda _: it2.get_next())
das_dataset_it = das_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        print(sess.run(it2.get_next()))
        print(sess.run(das_dataset_it.get_next()))
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman ! Yes the code above would blow with the rather cryptic `.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of type object where an element of type <class 'numpy.int64'> was expected.`, now makes sense. Thanks for fixing it on windows (the error I posted here is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13101 )

Comment: However as I commented here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13101#issuecomment-333422727 it would be nice to have a way to stitch together datasets - I guess allowing the generator to return Tensors would be a step towards this direction ? My usecase was a dataset of variable length tensors I then wanted to take slices of.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: mrry wrote tf.contrib.data ;)